# Can Django flush its database(s) between every unit test?

Tags: database, django, unit-testing

Django (1.2 beta) will reset the database(s) between every test that runs, meaning each test runs on an empty DB. However, the database(s) are not **flushed**. One of the effects of flushing the database is the `auto_increment` counters are reset.

Consider a test which pulls data out of the database by primary key:

```
class ChangeLogTest(django.test.TestCase):
    def test_one(self):
        do_something_which_creates_two_log_entries()
        log = LogEntry.objects.get(id=1)
        assert_log_entry_correct(log)
        log = LogEntry.objects.get(id=2)
        assert_log_entry_correct(log)
```

This will pass because only two log entries were ever created. However, if another test is added to `ChangeLogTest` and it happens to run **before** `test_one`, the primary keys of the log entries are no longer 1 and 2, they might be 2 and 3. Now `test_one` fails.

This is actually a two part question:

1. Is it possible to force `./manage.py test` to flush the database between each test case?
2. Since Django doesn't flush the DB between each test by default, maybe there is a good reason. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> is it possible to force ./manage.py test to flush the database between each test case?

Have a look on the implementation of the command of django.core.management.commands.flush.py.

You can call the flush command from inside your test call (maybe in TestCase.setUp):

```
management.call_command('flush')
```

> maybe there is a good reason. Does anyone know?

Yes there is: Speed up. Flushing and reloading many data from json takes a while...

Maybe you should have a look on [TransactionTestCase](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#django.test.TransactionTestCase)

Answer (score 9):

The answer to this is, don't write your tests in such a way as they depend on particular key values. For example, your test could better be written:

```
def test_one(self):
    do_something_which_creates_two_log_entries()
    logs = LogEntry.objects.all()
    assert_log_entry_correct(log[0])
    assert_log_entry_correct(log[1])
```

Comment: I guess that would work, since `LogEntry.objects.all()` always returns records in the same order (increasing primary key), right?

Comment: it is undefined, but most probably yes. If you want to be sure, just order results by id

Comment: @Mike, Ivan: ..or add `ordering = ('id',)` to Model.Meta

Comment: One way you can write the kind of test suggested by Daniel is using something like `jsonschema` and Swagger.   I imagine there are other ways, but this is just one that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [TransactionTestCase.reset_sequences](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/advanced/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.reset_sequences):

> Setting **reset_sequences = True** on a TransactionTestCase will make sure sequences are always reset before the test run:
>
> ```
> class TestsThatDependsOnPrimaryKeySequences(TransactionTestCase):
>     reset_sequences = True
>
>     def test_animal_pk(self):
>         lion = Animal.objects.create(name="lion", sound="roar")
>         # lion.pk is guaranteed to always be 1
>         self.assertEqual(lion.pk, 1)
> ```

Comment: It only works if the database backend has `supports_sequence_reset=True`, which not the case for SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

If you use any sort of "flush", keep in mind that if you've automated user creation or any other sort of data insert, it'll be deleted too.

An easy way to solve this problem without flushing is to get the ID of the first object during the test and increment from there.

```
Test1:
assertEqual(foo.id, 1)
assertEqual(bar.id, 2)

Test2:
start_id = Foo.objects.first().id
assertEqual(foo.id, start_id)
assertEqual(bar.id, (start_id + 1))
```